# Envio de objeto para cliente Android, o que usar?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android que é uma tabela de um campeonato de futebol com os resultados dos jogos apresentados em uma lista.

Na medida que os jogos acontecem eu cadastro em um banco de dados e envio o resultado para os clientes em Android.

Repare que os clientes apenas recebem as informações e não devolvem nada.

Gostaria de saber o que usar no envio das informações? Pretendo enviar um objeto do tipo jogo para o cliente através de um aplicativo simples em java que envia por socket esse objeto.

É isso que chamam de servelet? Ocorre que acho que socket não serve para envio de objetos, certo? Além disso quero algo que seja seguro e não sei se socket é a forma mais aconselhável para isso. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: caezar, sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Tente dividir seu problema em partes menores e mais diretas. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta aqui.

Comment: Usar uma url e exportar em um json, seria uma solução.

Comment: Mateus sua sugestão parece interessante, pode me dar mais informações?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me aprofundei mais nas sugestões dadas e creio que o melhor seja a união de WebService, SOAP e JASON ou XML.

Grato a todos pela força!

Comment: O problema de usar socket é que se um cliente estiver temporariamente inacessível (por exemplo sem acesso à rede), a mensagem enviada naquele momento é perdida. A sugestão para resolver isso seria usar push notification, por exemplo GCM. WebServices são uma opção ruim porque os aplicativos clientes fariam _polling_ continuamente para o servidor perguntando por novas mensagens, o que causaria consumo desnecessário de banda. Push notification é mais atraente porque é o servidor que toma a iniciativa de enviar a mensagem quando há algo novo para enviar.

Comment: Pode me explicar o que seria polling?

Comment: Quem sabe quando existe uma informação nova é o servidor. Então o mais adequado é que o servidor tome a iniciativa de enviar aos clientes as informações novas no momento em que elas ficam disponíveis. O contrário disso é _polling_: o cliente fica toda hora perguntando ao servidor: "tem informação nova?" "tem informação nova?", gastando internet e processamento do servidor desnecessariamente. Talvez [essa explicação](http://tassioauad.com/2014/06/05/entendo-o-conceito-do-google-cloud-messaging/) ajude a entender melhor (nela _"polling"_ está com o nome de _"pulling"_, os dois estão certos).

Comment: Legal cara entendi! Mas creio que o WS nesse meu caso tb geraria um problema  do tipo polling, pois o cliente tera que ficar acessando o WebService em busca de um jogo. Certo?
E pensando em segurança li muito que o melhor é HTTP. Você acha que o posso conseguir segurança tb com socket?

Comment: Certo. E segurança não é HTTP e sim HTTPS. Com socket você também consegue segurança, nos dois casos pode ser acrescentada uma camada de segurança usando por exemplo SSL. Mas ainda acho que você está indo pelo caminho errado; se usasse push notification (Google Cloud Messaging) resolveria todos esses problemas e mais o de garantir a chegada da mensagem mesmo em casos de perda momentânea de conectividade. A tecnologia por baixo do GCM são sockets seguros. Fazer de outra forma só vale a pena se você estiver querendo praticar o uso dessas tecnologias de base.

Comment: Legal! Vou procurar saber mais sobre GCM parece bem interessante! Obrigado pela ajuda!!